# Which is the best way to store text files into a Sql Server data base, for an asp.net mvc web application?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, text, store

I'm making a small asp.net mvc app. in which I have to compute data from several
CSV files ( between 5 to 10 files).

The application must provide upload and download actions for these files.

The part where I don't have experience is the data base. What column type should I use? text, image, binary ? the size of a file will be betweent 80KB to 500KB

Comment: Are you actually trying to store the entire file as an entity in the database, or do you simply want to upload the data within the csv file in a table?

Comment: I want to store the file as an entity.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The types `TEXT`, `NTEXT` and `IMAGE` are obsolete - do not use them for new development. They will be removed from a future SQL Server version for good.

For SQL Server 2005 and up, use `VARCHAR(MAX) / NVARCHAR(MAX)` if you're dealing with pure text files (like source code or CSV files), or `VARBINARY(MAX)` if you're dealing with binary files.

Those allow up to 2 GB of storage for each single file, and you can use all the usual T-SQL string functions on them to manipulate them (the (N)VARCHAR(MAX) fields, that is).

If you're using SQL Server 2008, there's also an additional option - the `FILESTREAM` attribute on `VARBINARY(MAX)` columns. This allows you to store the files in the SQL Server machine's file system (instead of the database tables) while preserving transactional and data integrity.

FILESTREAM is recommended for files that are typically and usually larger than 1 MB in size, or if you ever need more than 2 GB (since you can't store more than 2 GB in a regular `VARBINARY(MAX)` column).

Marc

Comment: Mention no limit FILESTREAM types as well for completeness.

Comment: Thank you all!
Solved, I guess I will use FILESTREAM.